# Usage of plotly libraries in python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using the `plotly` library to perform data analysis. However, I encounter a problem when trying to update the data as per the [official documentation](https://plot.ly/python/file-options/). The following error message appears,

[image]

Given below is my code.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4],
    y=[2, 1]
)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4],
    y=[3, 2]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4],
    y=[4, 3]
)
data = [trace0, trace1, trace2]

plot_url = py.offline.plot(data, filename='extend plot', fileopt='extend')
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. The offline plot function has no "fileopt" parameter and cannot be extended. Use the online version if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `plotly.offline` if you want to generate a HTML file.

```
import plotly.offline as py
# ...
py.plot(data, filename='extend plot', auto_open=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to do `import plotly as py` then `py.offline.plot`. Might work.

Also you need to set up you credentials for offline processing first. `import plotly
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='DemoAccount', api_key='lr1c37zw81')`

something like this. Please check out the link here [link here](https://plot.ly/python/offline/) also [this one](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/)

I think that will solve your problem.